# Different parent with the same name D3.JS

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, tree, nvd3.js

I am using d3.js to show a tree.

I parse the object json with contain `nameOfNode`, `NameOfParent`, the problem is if exist two node with the same name I have a problem.

What is the best approach to resolve it?

Comment: Please put a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodes, function(d){ 
    return d.name + d.id; 
});


svg.selectAll(".link").data(links, function(d){ 
    return d.source.name + d.target.name + d.id; 
});
```